# onMouseOut fires frequently when moved within anchor tag

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an anchor tag which has both a onMouseOver and onMouseOut event. The purpose is to display a tooltip. When I hover over the anchor tag, the onMouseOver event is appropriately triggered and the tooltip shows, but the onMouseOut event is also triggered and the tooltip is hidden. As I move the mouse over the anchor link, both events fire very frequently essentially making the tooltip flash visible and invisible very quickly. I want the onMouseOut to only fire once I'm outside the boundary of the anchor tag.

Code which I think is relevant:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a id="1" href="event.php?1" onmouseover="tooltip(this.offsetWidth, this.offsetHeight, this.childNodes, 1)" onmouseout="tooltipHide(1)">Text</a>
<div class="tt">
<div id="tt2" class="tooltip">
...
</div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<a id="2" href="event.php?2" onmouseover="tooltip(this.offsetWidth, this.offsetHeight, this.childNodes, 2)" onmouseout="tooltipHide(2)">Text</a>
<div class="tt">
<div id="tt2" class="tooltip">
...
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function tooltipHide(id) {
tt = document.getElementById("tt"+id);
tt.style.display = "none";
}

function tooltip(oW, oH, e, id) {
...
tt = document.getElementById("tt"+id);
tt.style.display = "block";
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little crazy but the issue was that the when the tooltip appeared, it overlapped with the text which triggered the event. For some reason, this caused both functions to trigger back and forth quickly. I fixed the problem by moving the tooltip away from the text.

Answer (score 1):

onmouseover is triggered anytime the mouse enters OR moves over the item being overed. You'd probably want `onmouseenter` show the tooltip, instead. That's triggered only when the mouse crosses the element's borders into the interior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave that a shot (onmouseenter, onmouseleave) and it responded for IE but not Chrome. Nonetheless, it gave a similar result where the tooltip displays and then hides very quickly as I move across the link. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed was that when I hover over the link and the tooltip displays, if I press the mouse button down, the tooltip disappears. If I release, it re-appears. Some extra info if it's helpful.